# Get exception messages from a custom SharePoint REST service

Tags: jquery, rest, web-services, angularjs

I am experiencing some difficulties in managing errors raised from a custom REST web service deployed to SharePoint ISAPI folder I developed.

My service is pretty simple. I deployed an .svc file to the ISAPI folder, and configured the service to use the `MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory` factory (the custom service is REST based).

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
Service="..."  
CodeBehind="....."
Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory, 
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

On the service I have a method configured as a WebInvoke operation:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Foo?param1={param1}&param2={param2}&param3={param3}&param4={param4}")]
bool Foo(string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4)
```

My main issue is not begin able to correctly handle errors raised by the service (for sake of simplicity, let just assume the service method just throws a new ApplicationException, you will see why later).

If my service method throws an exception, the call seem to just return with status `200-OK`, so jquery.ajax/angularjs $http think that the call has been successful and execute the promise success handler instead of the error one.

The only way I am able to actually have the error handler begin executed is if the exception I throw in my service inherits from `SystemException`: those exception seem to be handled in a different way and actually manage to trigger a 400 response. Still, in this case in my javascript error handler my error argument seem to be a string containing the SharePoint error page. I have confirmed by using the IE dev toolbar that in case of error, my service response body actually contains the full html source for the SharePoint error page.

I think I must be missing something obvious here. Can anyone provide help shedding some light on the issue? I would like to be able to receive just an error message from my service, just like SharePoint OOB REST services seem to be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more experiment, I have discovered that by switching to use actual `WebFaultException` instances, I can bypass the "return a custom error page" SharePoint behavior and receive the actual error message from my JavaScript based client. This way, I can have an AngularJS app consume my web service via $http, while receiving a custom error message and status code.

A different case should be made for authorization related exceptions. Those seem to be handled in a different way. The only way I have found for now to be able to manually handle those is by temporally disabling a web app setting during the web service method execution. I will post more details as soon as I have them.